# Control drawing order of points from DBMS in MapInfo?

Tags: mapinfo, draw-order

I have a layer of points stored in a table in a database (Oracle 11g). The table have a boolean field called `Supporting`. I have a thematic layer coloring the supporting points white and the non-supporting points red. Supporting points are often very close to non-supporting points. Since I am mainly interested in the non-supporting points I want to draw any red points on top of any white points. Can I accomplish this in MapInfo 11.5?

I have tried opening the table window and sorting it. That does not seem to affect the drawing order. I have also tried adding an `ORDER BY` column in the SQL when using "Expert mode" in the dialog "Open alternative for DBMS table". This do affect the drawing order, but not in a predictable or useful way.

*(English names of options and dialogs are translated from Swedish by me, so they may not exactly match the names in the english version of the software.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anders,

The draw order in MapInfo Pro for base tables (and DBMS tables as well) is controlled by the spatial index stored in the Map file.

The only way to control the order is by creating a query inside MapInfo Pro and with this order it to have the most important points last in the table. Queries are not displayed using the spatial index.

In your case, I would suggest that you open your data via two tables: One for the supporting points and one for the non-supporting points.

You can when opening that data from Oracle set a row filter where you specify a condition for each of the two tables.

Comment: Thank you! Do you by any chance know if making a query will cause MapInfo to download the entire DBMS table even though i am using "Live Access"? The long loading time suggests it does. Perhaps opening the data in two tables is better, but this becomes highly inconvenient in cases where there are many more than two categories.

Comment: Yeah, running a query on a live table in MapInfo will make MapInfo download all the data into your DBMS table. Performance wise it would be better to use a linked table if you know you will be running queries on the DBMS table